# bootstrap carousel on two div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

As you can see below I have two div's one is by the id By Senate and the other is 2nd div. I have a button on first div called view details. My requirement is when i click the view details button I want it to do a carousel and go to the 2nd div. I want to use bootstrap carousel.

I have tried some ways but it did not work out. Can somebody please help me.

```
<div id="BySenate" style="display: none">
    <table class="table table-hover table-responsive">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Party</th><th>Name</th><th>Chamber</th><th>District</th><th>State</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr dir-paginate="senate in senate|orderBy:['fullname']|filter:search|itemsPerPage:10" pagination-id="bySenate">
            <td> <img src="{{senate.party_name}}" style="max-height: 10%;max-width: 10%;"/> </td>
            <td>{{senate.fullname}}</td>
            <td > <img src="{{senate.chamber_type}}" style="max-height: 8%;max-width: 7%;"/>{{senate.chamber_name}} </td>
            <td>{{senate.district_name}}</td>
            <td>{{senate.state_name}}</td>
            <td>  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="{{senate.bioguide}}" value="{{senate.bioguide}}" ng-click="getLegislatorDetails($event);">View Details</button></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="2nd div">
</div>
```

Comment: you should not use space in classname or id, so "2nd div" is not a good idea. Aside from this problem, I am not sure if I understood what your requirement is

Comment: I have content in 2nd div...i just gave the 2nd div for your reference...I want the first div to slide left and display the 2nd div when the view details button is clicked

Comment: so you can simply write a scope function such that when you ng-click your ViewDetails button, the display flag for first div turns off, and the display flag for 2nd div turns on. This will hide first div and show second div

Comment: Ya I can do that but it wont give a carousel affect....I want the carousel affect of the 1st div sliding of and the 2nd div displaying.

Comment: then you can design your slide effect using css transform, and toggle your ngClass in your ngclick function